# Use findAll function of BeautifulSoup in webpages without tags

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm practicing with BeautifulSoup and I'm trying to extract the "isavailable" part of this website: https://api.meitre.com/api/calendar-availability-new/154/2/dinner

Given that there aren't any tags on it, I can't seem to find my way.

How can I use the findall function in this case? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's JSON data not HTML - so you don't want to be using BeautifulSoup here... use something like the `requests` library to retrieve the content of the page and call its `.json()` method and then you'll have a Python dictionary you can use to interrogate

Comment: I get it now. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon Clements mentioned that the url produces json data and to grab json data you can follow the next example.

```
import requests
import json

data = requests.get('https://api.meitre.com/api/calendar-availability-new/154/2/dinner').json()

# jsn_data = json.dumps(data)
# with open('data.json','w') as f:
#     f.write(jsn_data)

for item in data['calendarInfo']:
    date = item['date']
    available = item['type']

    print(date)
```

Output:

```
2022-03-02T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-03T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-04T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-05T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-08T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-09T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-10T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-11T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-12T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-15T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-16T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-17T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-18T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-19T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-22T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-23T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-24T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-25T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-26T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-29T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-30T00:00:00-03:00
2022-03-31T00:00:00-03:00
2022-04-01T00:00:00-03:00
2022-04-02T00:00:00-03:00
```

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you for taking the time to give me an example!

Comment: My bad, there you go!